# What exactly IS a "Domain Wall"?

Tags: astrophysics, high-energy-astrophysics, singularity

[A Domain Wall is an "topological defect" and a 2-dimensional singularity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_defect#Cosmological_defects) They are widely theorized to exist throughout the universe, but none have been detected yet. I'm having trouble understanding what they actually are though, the wikipedia articles and papers I looked at just have a lot of advanced mathematics.

1. Can light pass through a Wall? Do they emit/reflect any light.
2. Can matter pass through a Wall? If I were in a spacecraft, and I passed through a Wall, what would I see?
3. If it is a 2-d singularity, does it have an event horizon?
4. Does it have charge and spin like a black hole?

Comment: is https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9604090.pdf the sort of thing you're talking about?  Or https://guava.physics.uiuc.edu/~nigel/courses/569/Essays_Fall2012/Files/LIU.pdf

Comment: @JamesK The second one, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_defect#Cosmological_defects

Comment: I'm not sure whether 'wildly' wouldn't be the more appropriate adverb than 'widely'.

Comment: From wikipedia " if domain walls [...] were present in the observable universe, they would result in significant deviations from what astronomers can see."

Comment: vaguely related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYN9GWS1xjM

Comment: "Significant deviations" is about as vague as you can get